# Why is my .json returning undefined and giving the error "Unexpected end of JSON input"?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to complete an assignment for class and I can't figure out why my json is not working as intended. The specifics of the assignment are:

> Using React.js as a base, make a data-driven map application that
> contains this set of interactions:
>
> **Data**
>
> A .json file with at least five points of interest with this
> data: x and y locations, name of the location, a url to a picture of
> the location (included in your project), and a description of the
> location.
>
> **Layout**
>
> Project should have two panels: a left-side panel lists all the names
> of the locations. A right-side should display all of the locations (as
> a set of makers) on an IMAGE (it doesn't have to be a map like google
> maps). Yes, this means you could make a fantasy map or something else.
>
> Hidden initially should also be a series of popups that will be made
> visible in the interaction with the project.
>
> **Interaction**
>
> When clicking on an an a location name on the left bar -> highlight
> the corresponding marker on the map. When clicking on a marker on a
> map -> highlight the location name in the left bar AND display a popup
> above the map that shows all the related information.
>
> **Final points (10pts)**: Adjust the data so each location has a set of
> tags (i.e. "food", "hiking"). Create a third component that lists
> these tags. Clicking on one of these tags will "filter" the data
> displayed so that only the entries with those tags can be seen in the
> listing on the map.

Now I think that I have everything, but when I try to run this I receive the error "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError) Unexpected end of JSON input". From what I can tell from looking into the problem it's something with parsing the json into HTML but I can't figure out why I'm getting this problem.

What I have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import List from "./List";
import Points from "./Points";
import Tags from "./Tags";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      points: {
        data: [
          {
            id: 0,
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            name: "name",
            url: "url"
          }
        ]
      },
      selected: "none",
      tag: "none"
    };

    //load in the JSON
    fetch("data/data.json")
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(data => {
        //sets the json data to this.state.points
        this.setState({ points: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.points.data[this.state.selected]);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <List
          selected={this.state.selected}
          onSelection={choice => {
            this.changeSelection(choice);
          }}
          pointInfo={this.state.points.data}
        />
        <Points
          onSelection={choice => {
            this.changeSelection(choice);
          }}
          selected={this.state.selected}
          selectionChoice={this.state.points.data[this.state.selected]}
          pointInfo={this.state.points.data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  //changes the selected value in state
  //value of selected is send to Points and List
  changeSelection(num) {
    this.setState({ selected: num });
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And I don't know if the issue could stem from the actual json file, but my json is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "x": 500,
      "y": 500,
      "name": "Pittsburgh",
      "url": "./images/Pittsburgh.jpg",
      "description": "Pittsburgh is a city in western Pennsylvania at the junction of 3 rivers. Its Gilded Age sites, including the Carnegie Museum of Natural History, the Carnegie Museum of Art and the Phipps Conservatory and Botanical Gardens, speak to its history as an early-20th-century industrial capital. In the North Shore neighborhood are the modern Andy Warhol Museum, Heinz Field football stadium and PNC Park baseball stadium.",
      "tag": "historical"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "x": 700,
      "y": 220,
      "name": "Indianapolis",
      "url": "./images/Indianapolis.jpg",
      "description": "Indianapolis is the capital and most populous city of the U.S. state of Indiana and the seat of Marion County. As of 2017, Indianapolis is the third most populous city in the American Midwest and 16th most populous in the U.S., with an estimated population of 863,002.",
      "tag": "governmental"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "x": 450,
      "y": 100,
      "name": "Garland",
      "url": "./images/Garland.jpg",
      "description": "Garland is a city in the U.S. state of Texas. It is a large city located northeast of Dallas and is a part of the Dallas–Fort Worth metroplex. It is located almost entirely within Dallas County, except a small portion located in Collin and Rockwall Counties.",
      "tag": "historical"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "x": 480,
      "y": 240,
      "name": "Tampa",
      "url": "./images/Tampa.jpg",
      "description": "Tampa is a city on Tampa Bay, along Florida’s Gulf Coast. A major business center, it’s also known for its museums and other cultural offerings. Busch Gardens is an African-themed amusement park with thrill rides and animal-viewing areas. The historic Ybor City neighborhood, developed by Cuban and Spanish cigar-factory workers at the turn of the 20th century, is a dining and nightlife destination.",
      "tag": "historical"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "x": 650,
      "y": 100,
      "name": "Sacramento",
      "url": "./images/Sacramento.jpg",
      "description": "Sacramento, capital of the U.S. state of California, lies at the confluence of the Sacramento River and American River. The district of Old Sacramento harkens back to the city’s Gold Rush era, with wooden sidewalks and wagon rides. One of several museums in Old Sacramento, the California State Railroad Museum depicts the construction of the Transcontinental Railroad, one of the country’s earliest technological feats.",
      "tag": "historical"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something that I'm just missing here or have I completely missed the mark on what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with that JSON you posted.

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? Your `then()` is going to be triggered even for 404's. So if the path is not correct you are going to get a response that is not json(eg empty string) and therefore `result.json()` will cause an error. Check the network tab in dev tools and check your request and see what is actually being returned

Comment: @PatrickEvans Nothing but "undefined" prints out to the console. I can't figure out why either. The log points to line 31, the then() like you said. But I don't know how to fix it. I'm still learning how to do this and that line is just what the teacher said to use. How do I "correct" the path?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Well...I guess I solved it. I was using codesandbox.io cause that's what the teacher was using in class. On a hunch I just took my code from there and put it in a project in PhpStorm. And now it works fine. Still don't know what the issue was, but maybe it was more codesandbox than my actual code.